# Writing to COM port on C# or python

Tags: c#, windows-7, serial-port, pyserial

im trying to write a string to a COM4 which is a usb-serial adapter using Visual Studio C# and got the following error:

> Access to the port 'COM4' is denied.

My program is extremely simple:

```
serialport.Open();
serialport.WriteLine("test");
serialport.Close();
```

I also tried using pyserial with python and got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    ser.write("string")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 255, in write
    raise SerialException("WriteFile failed (%s)" % ctypes.WinError())
SerialException: WriteFile failed ([Error 6] The handle is invalid.)
```

I know this question isn't really related to programming and is probably a Windows 7 thing but I was hoping someone has already had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had nothing to do with permissions neither with the port being in use. I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028786/how-can-i-fix-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid-with-pyserial) which said it was because of the version I had installed (64 bit Python and 32 bit pyserial) I feel so silly.

What I still can't figure out is why it also didn't work on C# but that's OK. I'll just use python.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right click on your executable and choose "run as administrator". Windows 7 by default runs programs without admin privileges. I'm betting that the ability to write to a COM port requires running a program as an Administrator.

Comment: Did you try restarting your computer? Seriously, unplugging the device might screw things up, and this would fix that. Take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/49e8839e-e833-498d-a3a1-28922ec7bf43

Comment: The problem is I won't be able to to this for a python script. Haven't tried yet with the exe file.

Comment: ya i didnt restart it. Ok i ll let you know once i do that

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with permissions, the port is simply in use by another process.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple simultaneous connections to a serial port.  The port is likely in use.