# Using Serial on Python / Win7

Tags: python, windows-7, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to interface with a serial WWAN modem (for diagnostics /signal strength measurement purposes). This is via the onboard COM1 (115200-8-n-1) on my desktop, the connection works via PuTTY. I can script the AT commands using Python, but I am having a tough time getting it to open the serial port .

I have installed Python 2.7.1 and PySerial according to instructions. I am the local administrator of my machine and have run Python with and without admin privileges, but I get the following when I try to open the port:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 17:19:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>> s = serial.Serial(
...     port='COM1',
...     baudrate=115200
... )
>>> s.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 56, in open
raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self.portstr, ctypes.W
inError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port COM1: [Error 5] Access is
 denied.
```

It is my understanding that 8-N-1 is the default, and even when I try to set them manually it throws the same exception.

Can anyone offer advice? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to call `open`. The constructor already does that, and on Windows whoever opens a COM port has exclusive access to it until they close it.

As to the second problem, take a look at [How can I fix "[Error 6] The handle is invalid." with PySerial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028786/how-can-i-fix-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid-with-pyserial)

Comment: Thanks for the response @aix. I tried a different syntax in a new elevated py session, and am now getting a slightly different error:
`>> se = serial.Serial()
>> se.baudrate = 115200
>> se.bytesize = 8
>> se.stopbits = 1
>> se.xonxoff = 0
>> se.rtscts = 0
>> se.port = 0     # = COM1
>> parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
>> se.isOpen()
False
>> se.open()
>> se.write('AT\r\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    raise SerialException("WriteFile failed (%s)" % ctypes.WinError())
serial.serialutil.SerialException: WriteFile failed ([Error 6] The handle is invalid.)` Any ideas? 
PS Sorry re:format

Comment: @user330600: Could you edit your question to add this new info? The code/exception are a bit hard to read in a comment.

Comment: @user330600: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028786/how-can-i-fix-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid-with-pyserial

Comment: Thanks! 64-bit interpreters are a serious issue. Switching to 32bit worked!

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do to eliminate `Access Denied Error`:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>
2. Select `pythonw.exe` and press <kbd>End Process</kbd>
3. Re-Run your application in IDLE

It should be run without any access denied error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running `python.exe` in elevated mode. Right click and click `Run as administrator`