# Reading data in python from a COM port

Tags: python, python-2.7, port, tcomport

```
import serial
while True:
    ser=serial.Serial(port='COM30',baudrate=9600)
    print "try"
    s=ser.read(100) #reading up to 100 bytes
    print s
ser.close()
```

Device Manager:

[image]
I am trying to read data from port using python.
But it show the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_python.py", line 3, in <module>
    ser=serial.Serial(port='COM30',baudrate=9600)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 38, in __init__
    SerialBase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 66, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM30': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')

***Repl Closed***
```

Now from previous solution on stack I am tried using python 32 bit and call it from a cmd with admin priviledges but same error!

When I try it matlab it shows me this:

```
s = serial('COM30')

   Serial Port Object : Serial-COM30

   Communication Settings 
      Port:               COM30
      BaudRate:           9600
      Terminator:         'LF'

   Communication State 
      Status:             closed
      RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
      TransferStatus:     idle
      BytesAvailable:     0
      ValuesReceived:     0
      ValuesSent:         0
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit guys!

Answer (score 0):

Look like you haven't opened the serial port

```
ser=serial.Serial(port='COM30',baudrate=9600)
ser.open()
```

Also. What happens if you remove the loop?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6032694/3087339) that's not necessary. I wonder if there's an issue that each loop will try to open the port when it hasn't been closed after the previous loop.

Comment: @elParaguayo OK i did not know that.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Serial connections can be a hazzle. It seems to me that you try to open the port several times and you may have to kill the process that speaks with the com-port. I guess it is easiest to restart windows. Also you can try to 'ser.flushInput()' and 'ser.flushOutput()'

Answer (score 0):

```
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial(port='COM30',baudrate=9600)
ser.open()
while True:
    print "try"
    time.sleep(10)
    s=ser.read(100) #reading up to 100 bytes
    print s
ser.close()
```

Can you try this?

Comment: 'Access is denied.' : Did you check if some other service si running and locked this port?

Comment: Disable the COM port in the device manager window and enable it again, or use Portmon (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644)