# CherryPy: "Handle is invalid" when starting server

Tags: cherrypy

I am trying to start a CherryPy (v3.2.4) instance, but getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\servers.py", line 188, in _start_http_thread
    self.httpserver.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1836, in start
    self.bind(af, socktype, proto)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1883, in bind
    prevent_socket_inheritance(self.socket)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1599, in prevent_socket_inheritance
    raise WinError()
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid.
```

The server worked previously, and changing random parts of my Root class seems to make it the problem go away or come back. The symptoms are very similar to those descrobed in the resolved issue 1016:

https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1016/windowserror-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid

**UPDATE:**
I have a very large data-structure which exceeds 4GB. The above problem is occurs whenever I load that data. While my machine (and Python) can take it, it seems that CherryPy cannot. Is this worth reporting to the CherryPy dev community?

Comment: Can you show us the code of you webapp.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a 64 bit version Windows?

[How can I fix "[Error 6] The handle is invalid." with PySerial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028786/how-can-i-fix-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid-with-pyserial)

Try installing a  x86 version of python.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually have to use the 64-bit version of Python, because I have huge data-structures. As a matter of fact, that's probably what's causing the problem - if my memory exceeds 3-4GB, CherryPy won't start.