# Having trouble with making selenium work in no console mode on windows 7(pyinstaller compiled)

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

I'm trying to distribute a pyinstaller bundled python app which is a program controling selenium webdriver to do some routines, and I got `[Error 6] The handle is invalid` when trying to compile them with `--noconsole`. What do I do to fix the problem?

Environment: **windows 7 64bit  + python 2.7.3(32bit) + selenium 2.45.0**

Answer (score 0):

According to @Imbronder,

> Definitly a 64 bit problem atleast for me. I just installed an x86 version of python (3.1 this time), and it now works fine. Apperantly 64 bit ctypes can only import 64 bits libraries. Sounds very strange not being able to reach operating system libraries though.

Try installing the 32bit version of python and try again

*Source: [How can I fix "[Error 6] The handle is invalid." with PySerial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028786/how-can-i-fix-error-6-the-handle-is-invalid-with-pyserial#answer-3125289)*

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, the version of python installed on my computer is 32bit indeed, only win 7 is 64bit.