# django-wkhtmltopdf on IIS: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Tags: django, python-3.x, subprocess, iis-10

this is my very first question, so please forgive me, if I forgot something to mention or there's something wrong with it :)

I set up a python(3.5.3)-django(2.1.5) -project on IIS(10)-Windows Server. Everything works great.

### Problem

Only wkhtmltopdf(0.12.5) has a strange behavior.

When I run it on localhost the command prompt gives me

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

and I can find the generated .pdf-file in my downloads folder as expected.

When I change `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to the Server's IP and I call the url to generate a pdf it says there is a

> OSError at /pdf/
>
> [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

with the Traceback:

> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     154.                 response = response.render()
>
> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py"
>   in render
>     106.             self.content = self.rendered_content
>
> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf\views.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     80.             cover_template=self.resolve_template(self.cover_template)
>
> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf\utils.py"
>   in render_pdf_from_template
>     237.                           cover_filename=cover.filename if cover else None)
>
> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf\utils.py"
>   in convert_to_pdf
>     166.     return wkhtmltopdf(pages=pages, **cmd_options)
>
> File
>   "C:\my_project\myenv\lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf\utils.py"
>   in wkhtmltopdf
>     147.     return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py" in check_output
>     316.                **kwargs).stdout
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py" in run
>     383.     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py" in **init**
>     640.          errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\subprocess.py" in _get_handles
>     884.                 errwrite = _winapi.GetStdHandle(_winapi.STD_ERROR_HANDLE)
>
> Exception Type: OSError at /pdf/
>   Exception Value: [WinError 6] Das
>   Handle ist ungültig

I can see in `C:\Users\myapplicationpool\AppData\Local\Temp`-folder that wkhtmltopdf is generating a .html-file called for example `wkhtmltopdfgn1s7k5r.html` but somehow the progress gets stuck.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/issues/91) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368831/how-generate-a-pdf-file-with-django-wkhtmltopdf-on-iis-7-5-8) others had the same issue, too. But changing

```
if 'stdout' in kwargs:
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
```

to

```
if 'stdout' in kwargs:
    raise ValueError('stdout argument not allowed, it will be overridden.')
kwargs.pop('stderr', None)
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
```

has no effect. I think this solution only works for the subprocess.py-file of Python 2.7 and I am using Python 3+ and functions of this file changed.

I gave full permissions for `IUSR` & `IIS_USRS` -users to the wkhtmltopdf-folder where bin-folder & wkhtmltopdf.exe lie as I read that this could help as well, but it doesn't.

### Questions

Has anyone any other idea what I could try and help me please?

Does this issue really lie in the subprocesses of wkhtmltopdf & python or do I rather have to change/add handlers of my djangohandler of the FastCgiModule in IIS? How would I do so?

Why is it working when I run it on the server locally as localhost without any problems but not when I call the page via the server's IP? -- as mentioned: everything else works totally fine.

### Setup

I added wkhtmltopdf to `INSTALLED_APPS` and set it up like so:

settings.py

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = 'C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

(as I also read that there often is a problem due to spaces in paths when it is installed in `'Program Files'`.)

urls.py

```
path('pdf/', views.MyPDFView.as_view(), name='pdfview'),
```

views.py

```
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateResponse
class MyPDFView(View):
    template_name='mypdfview.html'

    def get(self, request):
        response = PDFTemplateResponse(request=self.request,
                                       template=self.template_name,
                                       filename='hello' + '.pdf',
                                       context=self.context,
                                       show_content_in_browser=False,
                                       cmd_options={
                                        'margin-top': 50,
                                        },
                                       )
        return response
```

mypdfview.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Some headline here.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Edit 1:
Somehow my greeting disappeared - added it...
Edit 2:
It seems I am not allowed to say: "Hi everyone"!?

Comment: yep, this is not a letter you're writing :-) see [ask]. Good question by the way. Sorry I don't have an answer. Just confirming that changing the code of _subprocess.py_ inside django-wkhtmltopdf won't do anything if you're running on python 3.x because `check_output` is already defined.

Comment: In _wkhtmltopdf/utils.py_, in the method `wkhtmltopdf()` at the end, just before the `return check_output(..)` line, try adding this: `if not ck_kwargs.get('stderr'): ck_kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE` or directly `ck_kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE` (if you always run in IIS). You'll need to `from subprocess import PIPE`.

Comment: Yessss, that did the job!! Thank you so much dirkgroten!

Comment: really? i'll add it as answer then. You might want to add this as a comment to the issue thread in the django-wkhtmltopdf github repo, seems more people are having this issue.

Comment: Did so......:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do the same workaround as proposed for python 2.7, you need to edit the *wkhtmltopdf/utils.py* file, method `wkhtmltopdf()`:

```
from .subprocess import check_output, PIPE

...

def wkhtmltopdf(pages, output=None, **kwargs):
    ...  

    except (AttributeError, IOError):
        # can't call fileno() on mod_wsgi stderr object
        pass

    # add this:
    if not ck_kwargs.get('stderr'):
        ck_kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE

    return check_output(ck_args, **ck_kwargs)
```

Comment: Maybe the import is better placed above to the other imports?

Changing:

from .subprocess import check_output

to:

from .subprocess import check_output, PIPE

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, but it's cleaner, yeah.